# what is the context argument in BaseOperator.xcom_pull

Tags: python, airflow

I was reading the API Docs, and was unclear what the *context* argument is for [BaseOperator.xcom_pull](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/code.html?highlight=xcom#airflow.models.BaseOperator.xcom_pull).

I thought it would be **dag.default_args**, but I receive `KeyError: 'ti'`

I performed an xcom_push within a prior task following the push() example [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py).

Answer (score 13):

The context is a set of keyword arguments containing reference objects related to a task instance, such as `dag`, `dag_run`, `run_id`, `execution_date`, etc. (including the task instance `ti` itself).

The default context is generated when task instance runs, and is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/4f20f607764bb3477419321b5dfd0c53ba1db3c0/airflow/models.py#L1523).

In the example you mentioned, the way context is passed in isn't super obvious: if the `provide_context` arg is set to True, Airflow will pass the generated context to the python callable. You can then access the task instance's [xcom_pull](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.TaskInstance.xcom_pull) method by calling `kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull()`.

So that's why for this to work, you will need to define `**kwargs` in your python callable's header, and set the operator's `provide_context` arg to `True`.

I am not sure how to directly get hold of the context reference though.

Comment: the official documents about xcom and provide_context is really confusing.